# Navigation of text fields inside cells that are re-used

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am attempting to allow a user the ability to cycle through all the text fields inside a table view (two text fields per cell) with arrow keys.

Currently what I am doing is setting a tag to each textfield, and adding each text field into an array.  Once the user clicks a text field to start editing it, some arrow buttons appear and when they press an arrow key, I grab the tag of the currently selected text field, use that as the location for the array, pull out the text field they want to go to, and set the new text field as the first responder.

The problem with this however, lies in the fact that my cells are re-used.  So if the user scrolls a cell offscreen, when it comes back, the cell in row 1 of the table may have the textfields with tags 15 and 16, and those are the end of the textfield array breaking my arrow keys.  And the more they scroll, the more the textfields get out of order.

Is it possible to accomplish what I am trying to do while still maintaining re-usable cells?  or will this just simply require that I do not re-use them?

Here is my arrow code...

```
- (void)arrowPressedHandler:(UIButton *)button
{
UITextField *newTextFieldSelection;

//tags are offset by 2 because I have use tag 1 for something else, and tag 0 cannot be used
int realLocation = selectedTextField.tag - 2; 

//arrow code.  for an up button i go back 2 slots in the array, right is + 1 in array
//etc etc 
@try{
    switch (button.tag) {
        case NumericKeyboardViewUpArrow:
            newTextFieldSelection = [textFields objectAtIndex:realLocation - 2];
            [newTextFieldSelection becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        case NumericKeyboardViewLeftArrow:
            newTextFieldSelection = [textFields objectAtIndex:realLocation - 1];
            [newTextFieldSelection becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        case NumericKeyboardViewRightArrow:
            newTextFieldSelection = [textFields objectAtIndex:realLocation +1];
            [newTextFieldSelection becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        case NumericKeyboardViewDownArrow:
            newTextFieldSelection = [textFields objectAtIndex:realLocation + 2];
            [newTextFieldSelection becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
@catch (NSException *e)
{
    return;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a slightly different approach.

Instead of giving all of the textField's different tags, give them a tag that is unique within each row, but the same between rows.  I.e. the left one gets tag 1000, and the right one gets 1001.  Then, use the indexPath's of the cells to get the appropriate row.  Your `arrowPressedHandler:` method would look something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
- (void)arrowPressedHandler:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = indexPathOfSelectedTextfield;
    UITextField *newTextFieldSelection;
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath;
    NSUInteger newTag = 0;

    @try{
        switch (button.tag) {
            case NumericKeyboardViewUpArrow:
                // Move back two textFields (which would be the one directly above this one)
                newIndexPath = selectedIndexPath - 1;
                newTag = selectedTextField.tag;
                break;
            case NumericKeyboardViewLeftArrow:
                // Move back one textField.
                if (selectedTextField.tag == 1000) {
                    // Selected text field is on left.  Select right textfield in the row above
                    newIndexPath = selectedIndexPath - 1;
                    newTag = 1001;
                } else {
                    // Selected text field is on right.  Select the left textfield in the same row
                    newIndexPath = selectedIndexPath;
                    newTag = 1000;
                }
                break;
            // etc.
        }
        [self.tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];
        newTextFieldSelection = [[self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath] viewWithTag:newTag];
        [newTextFieldSelection becomeFirstResponder];

    }
    @catch (NSException *e)
    {
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: I see.  I was tossing around ideas with the index path but this is better than anything I thought up so far.  This should work.  I'll test this out.  One question though, how would you get the 'indexPathOfSelectedTextField' value?

Comment: It gets a little more involved (making sure that you aren't at the first/last row, etc) but shouldn't be too hard.  Getting the indexPath of the row that the selected text field is in can be a little tricky.  Take a look at this answer for a good solution that I have posted in the past (bullet 3):  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14352372/937822

Comment: lol, getting the index path that way looks a bit hackey but it doesn't appear there is any elegant solution.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, that's exactly what that tableview method was designed for so I wouldn't call it hackey.  :)  It works quite well, and the only other solutions that I've found either require you to access the parents of the textview to find the cell (fragile) or you deal with the reuse of the cells and that leads to many corner cases that you have to deal with because of scrolling (as you've already seen).

Comment: Yeah it just seemed odd to me that you had to draw a rect over your object.  But thats what the method accepts so I guess its just the way its done.

Comment: One last question, the 2 lines for getting the indexPath of the text field is not returning any index paths inside the rect and causing a crash when trying to get the object at index 0 with an empty array.  Is this a problem with the frame not being drawn correctly?  I had to use self.view instead of just self as per your example

Comment: Oh, you don't actually draw a rect over it.  You are just supplying the frame of the object (which says where it is) to determine where it is in the table view.

Comment: Well, you need make sure that `selectedTextField` actually exists before you try to determine which indexPath it is associated with.

Comment: Well the issue is apparently the rect being drawn is not actually over or anywhere near the text field.  In fact, I created a label with a frame of the same location and its not even in the visible view.  the Y value is like -90 or something weird.  And I actually read somewhere about convertRect doing weird things on ipads.  I ended up just calling the superview of the textfield to get the cell itself, then find the cell's indexpath.

Comment: Well, I have only used that method on iPads so I'm not sure what your issue was, but I'm glad that you figured it out.  It is probably that you need to use self.tableview instead of self.view so that you convert it into the tableview's coordinate system.